# Checkbox control in Win32 API is rounded in a deformed manner in Windows 11

Tags: c++, user-interface, winapi, windows-11

As you can see in the following images:

[image][image]

there are unfilled areas when the checkbox is clicked(mainly in the corners). I have enabled visual styles through

```cpp
#pragma comment(linker,"\"/manifestdependency:type='win32' \
name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' \
processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
```

And I have also called `InitCommonControlsEx`

```cpp
INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX controls = { sizeof(INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX), ICC_STANDARD_CLASSES };
if (!InitCommonControlsEx(&controls)) { MessageBoxA(NULL, "Loading controls failed\n", NULL, 0); }
```

Here is my code for creating the button in WM_CREATE:

```cpp
int cx_check_box = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXMENUCHECK) - GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXEDGE);
int cy_check_box = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYMENUCHECK) - GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYEDGE);
HWND check_box = CreateWindowW(L"BUTTON", L"", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_AUTOCHECKBOX, 100, 100,
cx_check_box, cy_check_box, hWnd, NULL, (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_HINSTANCE), NULL);

if (!check_box)
    MessageBoxA(NULL, "check box creation failed :(", NULL, MB_RETRYCANCEL);
```

How can I go about making the checkbox occupy the entire space? Or make the extra space go away/transparent?
Thanks in advance for the help.

Windows SDK version - 10.0.22621.0 (which is windows 11 afaik)

Comment: Why are there two checkboxes in your image but only one in your code?

Comment: @PaulSanders: The sentence above that says **images**, as in plural. The one on the left is the unchecked version, while the one on the right is checked.

Comment: You can handle `WM_CTLCOLORBTN` and provide background for checkmark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle the [WM_CTLCOLORBTN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/wm-ctlcolorstatic?redirectedfrom=MSDN) message and set the background to Red.

[image]

```
case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC: 
    {
        static HBRUSH hBrushColor;
        if (!hBrushColor)
        {
            hBrushColor = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255, 0, 0));
            SetBkColor((HDC)wParam,RGB(255, 0, 0));
        }
        return (LRESULT)hBrushColor;
    }
    break;
```

Comment: Thanks this works, but it also works without the `SetBkColor((HDC)wParam,RGB(255, 0, 0));` for me. What's that point of that line?

Comment: I think it will be used for text background, but personally I set it as transparent, which allows to use more complicated brush background e.g. created from bitmap.